# Why is my code looping and displaying random lists from my for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project that goes like this:

Variables:

```
avail_res = [6, 4]
q_active = [2, 3, 4]
score = [3, 0, 10, 5]
populations = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]]

chromosomes = []
for num in score:
    if num <= avail_res[0]:
        chromosomes.append(populations[score.index(num)])
        if len(chromosomes) > 1:
            k = random.choice(chromosomes)
            chromosome_best = k
        else:
            chromosome_best = chromosomes

act = numpy.array([q_active[i] for i in numpy.flatnonzero(chromosome_best)])
```

The objective is to get activity in `q_active` corresponding to the non-zero value in `chromosome_best`. With the code above, the 1st step is to compare each element in `score` to `avail_res[0]`. If it satisfies the condition, then its corresponding `population` will be obtained and stored in `chromosome_best` where the non-zero value is used to get corresponding element in `q_active`. If `chromosome_best` is more than 1, then, it should choose which to select randomly.

The problem is after getting the output, the for loop is still 'looping'. So I am getting an output like this:

```
Output = [[1, 0, 0]] # obtained from the first loop
          [0, 0, 0] # randomly selected on the 2nd iteration of for loop
          [0, 0, 0] # randomly selected on the 3rd iteration of for loop

Expected Output for Populations = [[1, 0, 0]]
Expected Output for act = [2]
```

How could I make my code free from looping but still consider it when checking for the condition ( `<= avail_res[0]` )?

I tried making it `if [num <= avail_res[0] for num in score]:` but `num` gets undefined.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your code to be structured more like:

```
numpy
import random

avail_res = [4, 6]
q_active = [2, 3, 4]
scores = [3, 2, 8, 10]
populations = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]]

chromosomes = []

for score in scores:
    if score <= avail_res[0]:
        chromosomes.append(populations[scores.index(score)])

chromosome_best = random.choice(chromosomes)

act = numpy.array([q_active[i] for i in numpy.flatnonzero(chromosome_best)])

print(chromosome_best)
print(act)
```

An open question in my mind is why you only look at `avail_res[0]` and not the rest of `avail_res` -- i.e. we need to understand more about what's going on.  Also, no need to handle a single entry in `chromosomes` specially, the `random.choice()` function will cope just fine.

Comment: The code presented above actually belongs to a bigger for loop. The problem that I am getting now is whenever I try to run the it, length of chromosomes gets bigger. For example, scores = [3, 2, 8, 10], avail_res[0] = 4, populations = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]. The score in scores satisfying the condition should be 3 and 2 with populations = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]. Therefore, I should be choosing randomly which to put in chromosome_best. Then, find its corresponding value in q_active.

Comment: the problem is, using this code, I don't get the chromosomes that I need. Instead, it gives me something like this: chromosomes = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]], and its length gets larger and larger because of 'append' instead of just having the chromosomes of the score in scores satisfying the condition.

Comment: @JohnAndreiGayeta, I reworked my code with the example input you provided in your first comment and the value of `chromosomes` was `[[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]` as expected.  If there's a bigger picture to consider, then *you* have to provide it to us.